# Can an Artillerist use their eldritch cannon as a focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer, spellcasting-focus

I'm trying to parse out how to wear a shield, still be able to cast spells, and mitigate the cannon's abysmal walking speed in between encounters. Perhaps a shoulder mount, a la "Predator"?

Answer (score 13):

#### The cannon cannot be a focus, but there are other options.

The rules for Artificers and Spellcasting focuses are more restrictive than other caster classes. An artificer *must* use their tools as a focus for *all* their spells:

> You produce your artificer spell effects through your tools. *You must have a spellcasting focus—specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature* (meaning the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it).

However, starting at second level, an item you infuse with one of your infusions can be a focus:

> After you gain the Infuse Item feature at 2nd level, you can also use any item bearing one of your infusions as a spellcasting focus.

So you could infuse your shield with one of your infusions and use it as a focus. Further, at 5th level, the artillerist gets an Arcane Firearm that is usable as a focus:

> You know how to turn a wand, staff, or rod into an arcane firearm, a conduit for your destructive spells. […]
>
> You can use your arcane firearm as a spellcasting focus for your artificer spells.

Since nothing in the Eldritch Cannon description talks about it being usable as a focus, it isn’t usable as a focus. But there are other options available.

As for transporting the cannon between combat encounters, just pick it up. There’s no reason you shouldn’t be able to carry it.

Comment: I'm never sure when questions come up about spellcasting foci if the querents are aware that having a focus only matters for spells with material components. You can "cast spells" without a focus just fine, for a slightly narrower set of spells. So maybe worth emphasising that artificers have quite a few spells that are castable without recourse to a focus.

Comment: @Marq, It's worth emphasising that, as mentioned in the answer, "You **must have a spellcasting focus** —specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature (meaning **the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it**)." So every Artificer spell has a material component, even  if doesn't list one.

Comment: @Marq As I mentioned in my first sentence, *the rules for artificers are more restrictive*. **All** artificer spells must be cast with a focus.

Answer (score 1):

### An *eldritch cannon* isn't an infusion.

While you can make an eldritch cannon tiny and leg-less and carry it around like a gun, the cannon is neither a tool set nor an infused item, so you can't use it as your focus. You need something else.

### Your shield could be an infused item.

The simplest solution here is to use an infusion on your shield, making it into a valid focus for your spells. Then you can keep your cannon in hand in "gun" mode and still do everything else you need to do.  But that's not the only option.

### You don't need a focus in hand at all times.

If you're only worried about moving the cannon around between fights, just put your focus away when you aren't actively using it and carry your cannon. You can always draw the focus as a free object interaction when you need to. (Dropping the cannon isn't an object interaction, after all.)

### The shoulder mount.

With DM permission, a small, legged eldritch cannon should be able to ride on your shoulder or back and still do its thing. Arguably this makes more sense with the Protector, which is sort of omni-directional, but if not, you could have it just drop off you as part of its move the first time you use it each encounter.

Comment: The cannon itself isn't an Infusion, but it could theoretically receive an Infusion if its form meets the requirements for the Infusion in question.